# VarBinary to image url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am converting a base64 image to `byte[]` and storing this in a `varbinary` column in SQL Server. I want to get the image from the database and set this as image url of an ASP.NET `image`.

How can I do that?

Code for writing image to database:

```
 string str= myBase64.Value.Substring(17);
 byte[] myByte = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Comment: I think , firstly , you have to write your binary image to physical path of your project  !

Comment: how?Is there any way to directly set the image source

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
<img src="GetBinary.aspx?id=123" />
```

or

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="GetBinary.aspx?id=123" />
```

then in GetBinary page_load (or if MVC, use an action that returns null).

```
//resp is HttpResponseBase or just use Response.

resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
resp.BinaryWrite(myByte);
resp.Flush();
resp.End();
```

**Edit:** Here is an ASHX version

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" 
    CodeBehind="AssetHandler.ashx.cs" Class="NameSpace.AssetHandler" %>


//-- codebehind
public class AssetHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // place response code here using context.Response
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to set it for an asp image

Comment: How to convert the varbinary from DB to Base64 to set it as imageUrl?

Comment: I made a test with this. It works for me. What dont you understand?

Comment: Minor edit: I'd recommend using an ASHX (http handler) instead of a page for this, it's much lighter weight.  Also, depending on the size of the image, you might want to consider output caching.

Comment: ahh, digging up old webform code. Mvc, never looked back. Thanks for reminding me, i have updated.

Answer (score 2):

If the images are small, take a look at [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)'s. You can put the image data in the link itself. When you have a `byte[]`, use `Convert.ToBase64String` on it. Format the URI according to the specs, and voila, there's the image. But like I said, please pay attention to specs, size limits, [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri), etc. For small icons or such, I would definitely use data URI's now.

Comment: How to convert the varbinary from DB to Base64 to set it as imageUrl?

Comment: I updated my answer. I was a bit vague, I was on my mobile when I wrote it.