# How to load image from Binary Image Data in Balkan Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing Organizational Chart in BalkanGraph. Images in BalkanGraph are loading from URL and its working fine. I want to load the binary image into it (The binary image is coming SQL Server). How can I load it?

Here is the link to [BalkanGraph exmaple](https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Demos/Grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image to Base64 (encode to Base64). You can do it on your server.

After converting you will get the result as:

data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw

Comment: Thankyou BalkanGraph, but I have already done it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520441/varbinary-to-image-url). Your solutions looks easy and good, Next time I will try this. Thank you